# traefik + letsencrypt wildcard certificate + no provider

Tags: dns, certificate, wildcard, lets-encrypt, traefik

I would like to configure `[acme.dnsChallenge]` section in traefik reverse proxy as explained here: https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/acme/

As you can see, I should set a provider name in this section. There are bunch of examples like  `digitalocean`, `cloudfare` etc. The thing is, I don't have any provider from the list. However, I have some provider and it has DNS API so in theory I am able to automate DNS-01 chanllenge. My question is: how can I use non-supported provider? What should I specify in the configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- [`exec`](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/acme/#provider)
- [`httpreq`](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/acme/#provider)
- [`acme-dns`](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/acme/#provider)
- [`manual`](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/acme/#provider)

We don't recommend using `manual` because it don't allow to renew certificates automatically.

You can also open an issue on [lego](https://github.com/go-acme/lego) or do a pull request on [lego](https://github.com/go-acme/lego) to add your provider.

More information:

- https://go-acme.github.io/lego/dns/exec/
- https://go-acme.github.io/lego/dns/httpreq/
- https://go-acme.github.io/lego/dns/acme-dns/
- https://github.com/joohoi/acme-dns

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can use a provider that isn't supported. Each uses their own APIs. If you can, I suggest migrating over to a supported DNS provider.